# Переключение между UiViewController-ами из кода в Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Привет!
Подскажите как переключиться с вьюконтроллера на вьюконтроллер из кода без использования кнопки?
Т.е. нужна следующая логика
if(что то там){
переключить на вторую вьюшку.
}

Comment: @x3zone, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Для начала. Туда:

```
[self presentViewController:someController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Обратно:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Спасибо!То что нужно.